# aws s3 upload for freeform pro upload field type

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads, s3, aws

i started working on a simple extension that hooks to freeform's pro "freeform_module_insert_begin" hook.

basically the purpose of it is to check if the form has a "file upload" field(s) and if yes, then upload those files to S3 server and update the links that get submitted to database.

i was wondering what would be the easiest way to check if the form has upload file field(s)

cheers,
Mark

Comment: got it sorted other way ... placed a custom hook just before the files are uploaded in the "post_save" public function ... works fine!

Comment: Hi Mark, I would be interested in purchasing a copy of this extension if you're willing to make it available? I have a project where I need to catch uploads and send them to S3 also... :)